# Blank space on top of wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a weird problem, in one of my website a blank space is add on top the of the site under the body.

The blank space is display on chrome and internet explorer and not in firefox.

the website url is dune.quai13.net

If you have and idea :)

Thank !

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your header you have a white space. Remove that and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an invisible char at the top of your page `<feff>`. This may be due to the editor you used who inserted a wrong char (typically in windows editors, or when converting file charset), or if there is a newline at the end of a php file ( after the `?>` ).

If someone else did the theme, maybe you can ask him for support.

Answer (score 0):

As @Howlin said in his answer while inspecting the site in firebug there is a blank space at the starting of body.

**AND**

One major problem that i found out in your page while inspecting was that you have kept your `<links>`,`<meta>` tags etc inside your `<body>` tag which is not at all correct.You have to include those inside the `<head>` tag.

According to W3Scools

> The `<head>` element is a container for all the head elements. Elements
>   inside  can include scripts, instruct the browser where to find
>   style sheets, provide meta information, and more.

Comment: please stop sharing links to w3schools... they contain lots of outdated and misleading information and is totally unofficial...

Comment: <script> tags can go anywhere. For example, it's quite common to put them above the closing body tag